# Bluetooth not working after suspension

Tags: suspend, bluetooth

I'm new to Ubuntu and I wiped Windows completely on my Asus X456U laptop...recently I've found out that I have some issues regarding the bluetooth:

When I first boot the laptop after a reboot or a power on, the bluetooth works fine, and I can connect my headphones or devices. But if I suspend the laptop, the bluetooth either: wont find bluetooth devices anymore, or find some but won't conect to them.

I tried doing [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211) but it did not work

Any other options?

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04
[Laptop details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTxOv.png)

Comment: After trying a lot of stuff (even updating the kernel)...Updating to 18.10 solved the problem for me